# When the deadline starts to count down?

Tags: grpc

I have a question about when the deadline starts to count down? Does the deadline start to count down when arguments are marshaled and waiting to be sent, or after the arguments are sent out?

Answer (score 0):

A deadline refers to a specific moment in time, usually in the future. It's like an alarm for a specific time, rather than a timer for a specific amount of time. So, for example, if you set a deadline of `now + 1 second`, it is by definition counting 1 second from when you performed that calculation. If you set the deadline to `4:30 PM today`, it doesn't matter when you start counting, because that doesn't change when the deadline will be reached.

The client converts the deadline to a duration when sending it to the server, and then the server counts from when it receives it. Those calculations do not account for the transit time, so that timer will have a slight delay added. However, he deadline on the server is just for determining when it is no longer useful to continue processing a request, so it doesn't need to be precise.

Comment: It definitely does matter. Is transit time included from when the deadline time start counting?

Comment: I expanded my answer. Does that address your question?

Comment: Yes, that clarified it thanks